# Uploading .rar file to wordpress media library

Tags: wordpress, rar

I am trying to allow uploading of .rar files to wordpress media library by editing functions.php of my theme by adding following code to it. but it doesn't work.
Could you please tell me where i am wrong?
Regards

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'my_myme_types', 1, 1 );
function my_myme_types( $mime_types ) {
$mime_types['rar'] = 'application/vnd.rar';
return $mime_types;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks right (except the MIME type should be `application/x-rar-compressed` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types).

Anyway, I had the same problem once and 
`$mime_types['rar'] = 'application/x-rar-compressed'` did not work either.

So I ended up with putting:
`define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);`
in the wp_config.php.

This could be an option for you, but obviously it does much more than you actually want, so be careful.

Comment: This mime seems also invalid, I tried this one and it works perfectly ```application/x-rar```
Found it here : ```https://gist.github.com/termitkin/32d842a087744a034f72aa2ba16e6df9```